# Problem accessing an Apache-hosted folder

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, subversion, access-control

I'm running Centos 6.2, and Apache. I'm running into an error to do with access rights/permissions when trying to navigate to a webpage. I'm trying to go to the URL `http://localhost/repos`, but I get the error:

> You don't have permission to access /repos on this server

Am I missing something essential? I've tried running `chmod 775`, which I believe should have given me the correct access rights, but to no avail.

Comment: First figure out what physical directory is related to `http://localhost/repos`. Then check all parent directories of proper privileges for the user your webserver is running under.

Comment: What error appears in the logs?

Answer (score 1):

Run `restorcon -Rv` on the directory in question.  If it's permissions, and `chmod` doesn't fix it, it's probably selinux.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your permission directives (allow/deny) in your httpd.conf (or includes) are correct?